# Android Alarm Volume increase gradually

Tags: android, media, volume, android-alarms, android-audiomanager

I have an Alarm class which plays the default alarm tone on time. I want to make the alarm tone play, volume from minimum to maximum within a time. How can i increase the volume gradually from minimum to maximum. Is there any links for sample codes or projects. please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by yourself. Nothing complicated in it.

Once your `PendingIntent` is triggered, make use of handlers to do the increasing.

1. Create class that will take the `AudioManager` or `Context` of the app as argument.

   ```
     public class VolumeRunnable implements Runnable{

   private AudioManager mAudioManager;
   private Handler mHandlerThatWillIncreaseVolume;
   private final static int DELAY_UNTILL_NEXT_INCREASE = 30*1000;//30 seconds between each increment
   VolumeRunnable(AudioManager audioManager, Handler handler){
      this.mAudioManager = audioManager;
      this.mHandlerThatWillIncreaseVolume = handler;
   }

   @Override
   public void run(){
      int currentAlarmVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
      if(currentAlarmVolume != mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)){ //if we havent reached the max

      //here increase the volume of the alarm stream by adding currentAlarmVolume+someNewFactor
           mHandlerThatWillIncreaseVolume.postDelayed(this,DELAY_UNTILL_NEXT_INCREASE); //"recursively call this runnable again with some delay between each increment of the volume, untill the condition above is satisfied. 
      }

   }
   ```

   }
2. Call this `Runnable` once the `PendingIntent` is triggered:

> someHandler.post(new VolumeRunnable(mAudioManager, someHandler));

I hope this gave you idea. Forgive any mistakes or typos.

Comment: You missed:
Handler someHandler = new Handler();

before:
someHandler.post(new VolumeRunnable(mAudioManager, someHandler));
Just a comment for others.